# Scala Spark | IntelliJ compilation error on .read and .write

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

Im new to scala spark. I m trying to read a csv file from S3 and write it into cassandra. The code below on compilation in IntelliJ gives me errors.
Not sure What am I doing wrong. Appreciate your inputs in advance.

scala : 2.11.12
Spark : 2.4.3

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DoubleType, StringType, StructField, StructType, IntegerType}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

object OrderAdjustmentLoad
{
  def main(args:Array[String])=
  {
    val awsAccessKeyId: String     = args(0)
    val awsSecretAccessKey: String = args(1)
    val csvFilePath: String        = args(2)
    val host: String               = args(3)
    val username: String           = args(4)
    val password: String           = args(5)
    val keyspace: String           = args(6)

    println("length args: " + args.length)

    val conf = new SparkConf(true)
      .set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", awsAccessKeyId)
      .set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", awsSecretAccessKey)
      .set("fs.s3n.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", host)
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.port","9042")
      .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", username)
      .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", password)

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val schemaHdr = StructType( StructField("a2z_name", StringType) ::
      StructField("a2z_key", StringType) ::
      StructField("a2z_id", IntegerType) :: Nil
    )

    val df = sc
      .read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("delimiter", "\t")
      .option("quote", "\"")
      .schema(schemaHdr)
      .load("s3n://"+csvFilePath)

    println(df.count())

    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    df.write
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
      .option("keyspace","poc_sparkjob")
      .option("table","a2z")
      .mode(org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode.Append)
      .save

    sc.stop()

  }
}
```

Errors
**Cannot resolve symbol read**
**Cannot resolve symbol write**

Comment: `read` & `write` are methods from **SparkSession**, not from **SparkContext**. Take a look to the [_SQL - Getting started documentation_](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html).

Comment: added the below code 
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("S3 to Cassandra | Scala Spark - POC")      
      .getOrCreate()

compilation error gone. But on executing getting error "Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243)", what to do ?

Comment: A **SparkSession** initialize an **SparkContext**, thus you should not create your own. If you need access to it, you can call the `sparkContext` method on an instance of a **SparkSession** to get it. _(`val sc = spark.sparkContext`)_

Comment: Thank you.

Earlier, i was trying to get "spark" object by creating a session, which caused me "only session should be running" error.

val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("S3 to Cassandra | Scala Spark - POC")
      .getOrCreate()

You suggested to use **"val sc = spark.sparkContext"** instead of above code. But i don't have a "spark" object, without which "spark.sparkContext" is throwing error. How do i get the "spark" object.?

Comment: You said you got _"Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243)"_ I supposed that was caused because you initialize both the **SparkSession** and the **SparkConext**. Now, if the error is that you have two sessions, you should check where else in the code that is happening? - PS: Note that, if you are pasting the code on a `spark-shell` or `Jupyter / Zeppelin` Notebook, usually both _spark_ & _sc_ already exist.

Comment: It worked when I run in spark-shell, but not in intelliJ as an object as code shown above.

Comment: Please update the question with the code you have now, and add the exact error message you are getting, and explain how are you running the application to get such error.